# What is .sencha/app/Boot.js for?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm upgrading from ExtJs 4.2 to ExtJs 6.2.

I started with the default app.js, and then I disabled the loading of `ext-all-debug.js` by removing

```
{
    "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-debug.js"
}
```

from the `js` property in `app.js`.

Now I see an error 404 in the console for the file `.sencha/app/Boot.js`, while the application still continues to work as expected.

Can anyone explain, what this file `.sencha/app/Boot.js` is used for in ExtJs 6.2 ?

**Edit:**
What I do not understand: I looks as if the code in `.sencha/app/Boot.js`is already included in `bootstrap.js`. Also that code is used to load all the files referenced in `bootstrap.json`.

Why would `bootstrap.js` load `Boot.js`, when the code in `Boot.js` is already executed before it is loaded ? It looks as if ExtJs is somehow incoherent in its bootstrap process, unless there is something I don't understand.

bootstrap.json

```
{"paths":
    {"Ext":"../../ext/classic/classic/src",
    "Ext.AbstractManager":"../../ext/packages/core/src/AbstractManager.js",
    ...
    "Ext.Boot":"../../.sencha/app/Boot.js",
```

Comment: From a comment in Boot.js: "The Boot loader class manages Request objects that contain one or more individual urls that need to be loaded"

Comment: Did you run: sencha app upgrade

Comment: @kevin No, I didn't run `sencha app upgrade`. I made a fresh install, copied the old sources in the new app and compiled it.

Comment: you still get the same error after that?

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer the question:

I copied over that file and the error 404 is gone, obviously.